# Passing a range from one VB function to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a few VBA functions for work and ran into a problem that should be easy to solve, but somehow I can't manage to, despite my best attempts at finding an answer here and on Google. I wrote a function that should give me the range between two strings in a column:

```
Function FindRng(StartRng As String, EndRng As String) As Variant
Dim TopOfRange As Single
Dim BottomOfRange As Single

TopOfRange = WorksheetFunction.Match(StartRng, Sheets("InfCom").Range("B:B"), 0)
BottomOfRange = WorksheetFunction.Match(EndRng, Sheets("InfCom").Range("B:B"), 0)

FindRng = Range(Sheets("InfCom").Cells(TopOfRange, 2), Sheets("InfCom").Cells(BottomOfRange, 2)) 
End Function
```

So if the inputs A and B are on rows 100 and 105, it should return B100:B105. When I test this by adapting the code to read FindRng = Range(...).Address, I indeed get $B$100:$B$105.

However, when I then input the result of FindRng into a customized Index Match function, I get an error. The function is as follows:

```
 Function subsetPBPC(rngReturn As Range, LookupValueH As Variant, TopOfRange As String, BottomOfRange As String, LookupValueV As Variant) As Variant

subsetPBPC = sPBPC(rngReturn, LookupValueH, FindRng(TopOfRange, BottomOfRange), LookupValueV)

 End Function
```

The problem is that it seems to read the output of FindRng not as a range, but as the content of that range: when I use the Evaluate Formula tool on FindRng embedded in another formula, it shows the output of FindRng as {A,B,C,D,E} instead of $B$100:$B$105, where A to E are the contents of the cells in the range. I have the feeling the solution is really simple, but I don't see it. The functions underlying the customized Index Match function have been tested and all work like a charm.

Comment: try to declare your function as a range : Function FindRng(...) As Range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set instead of let. Let assigns the value of an expression to a variable. Set assigns an object reference to a variable. You want to return a reference to the range object, not return the value produced by the range object's default property.

In VBA writing

```
FindRng = Range(...)
```

is implicitly writing

```
Let FindRng = Range(...)
```

However you want

```
Set FindRng = Range(...)
```

Edit 1:
It is quite important to understand the difference between an object reference and a value in VBA. This is a similar concept to passing arguments by value or by reference. Hopefully these two links help some:
[The Let statement on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243390(v=vs.60).aspx)
[The Set statement on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266283(v=vs.60).aspx)

Edit 2:
Oh, and I guess I should touch on default properties! Some objects like range have default properties. If you treat the range as a value instead of an object, it uses the default property instead of throwing an error because it's an object not a value. In the case of range the default property is `Value`. So if you say `A = Range("A1")` what you're actually saying is `Let A = Range("A1").Value` when you might mean `Set A = Range("A1")`. So you're getting the value contained in the cell A1, instead of a range object representing that cell.

Comment: Thanks AndASM! That was a useful explanation that solved the problem.

Comment: See brettdj's answer as well. Using the most specific type you can, like a Range instead of a Variant if you're always returning or passing a range is a good idea. It helps prevent and detect errors, as well as potentially running faster.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up that your current code should both

- use `Set` as per AndADM's commnet
- dimension `SetRng` as a *Range* rather than *Variant*

you can simplify your function as below (which may save time if you are calling it repetitively)

Also, you could test for this range being `Nothing` (if your two strings werent found), whereas you current code will error out if either string is missing.

```
Function SetRng(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Range

With Sheets("infCom").Columns(2)
    Set SetRng = Range(.Find(str1, , xlValues, xlWhole), .Find(str2, , xlValues, xlWhole))
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Yeah, I was going to comment on the virtues and benefits of using the most specific types you can, rather than a general type like Variant. But my answer was already getting a bit hefty. :)